# Screen selection settings, keyboardless

Tags: multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

In Windows, you can access the screen selection menu using combination <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, like the following (taken from Win 7 and provided only as an example)

[image]

Now in Windows 10 I find myself in a situation where I want to switch from seocndary-only to primary-only screen (option 4 to 1) **without physical access to keyboard**.

Is it possible to do so by mouse?

Note: I know I could enter Screen settings to change monitors, **but** it will trigger a 15 seconds countdown after which screen settings are restored. Not being physically able to confirm within 15 seconds because, as you can now imagine, the monitors are physically far.

Note 2: mirroring the distant screens is **not** an option in my case

Comment: You can do the Win+P combo with the On-Screen Keyboard. You could also do what you did in your first `Note` and use the On-Screen Keyboard to select with arrow keys and press Enter. What do you mean when you say the monitor is far away? You can't see what the mouse is doing because it is too far?

Comment: Exactly. The monitors are in separate rooms, one connected by a loooooooooooooong HDMI cable. OSK is clever idea anyway!

Comment: Does it work for you? I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Please do! I just tried and found it amazingly working fine!

Answer (score 2):

Use the **On-Screen Keyboard** to do the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> combination.

Comment: it also works..

Comment: Aha no. I can't use OSK to confirm, because if I switch off the screen I am looking at with my *wireless* mouse, I can't reach (or need to be very fast) the other screen within 15 seconds to press the onscreen keyboard with my mouse

Comment: I see, I've removed it. You potentially could though if you memorized what keys needed to be pressed. I think the option automatically highlighted first is `Revert`. You could press the left arrow once and then Enter, that should be Keep changes.